# Error during select query MDX - Members, tuples or sets must use the same hierarchies in the function

Tags: c#, asp.net, mdx, olap, cube

I'm trying to get the Lattitude & Longitude of shops from OLAP Cube which will be passed in google map.

I tried the following query:

```
select
{
[Productive_GIS].[Lat].[Lat],
[Productive_GIS].[Lon].[Lon]
} on columns,
[Productive_GIS].[SHOPCODE WITHOUT DIST].[SHOPCODE WITHOUT DIST] on rows
from
[Consolidated Sales]
```

I am getting the following Error:

**Query (2, 1) Members, tuples or sets must use the same hierarchies in the  function.**

I want the result set in ONE of the following two formats:

[image]

OR

[image]

The snapshot of the CUBE:

[image]

Kindly Help me achieve this as I'm new to MDX.
I will be converting this resultset into Asp DataTable for further proceeding on Google Maps

Answer (score 0):

Can you try just crossjoining the 3 hierarchies?

```
SELECT
{} on columns,

[Productive_GIS].[Lat].[Lat] *
[Productive_GIS].[Lon].[Lon] *
[Productive_GIS].[SHOPCODE WITHOUT DIST].[SHOPCODE WITHOUT DIST] 
on rows
from
[Consolidated Sales];
```